# How can I use pygame.time.Clock.tick() in java?

Tags: java, swing, while-loop, jframe, frame-rate

In python's pygame module, we can use:

```
pygame.time.Clock.tick(90)
```

to limit FPS in game, but it's only works on python, what about java?

I tried to use:

```
public void paint(Graphics canvas){
    long begin_time = System.currentTimeMills();

    // do Jframe paint / game loop here

    long MSPT = System.currentTimeMills() - begin_time;

    if (MSPT < 10){
        try {
            Thread.sleep(10 - MSPT);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.println("FPS: " + (1000 / (System.currentTimeMills() - begin_time)));
}
```

but each time FPS is not same:

```
Terminal
FPS: 83.33333333333333
FPS: 83.33333333333333
FPS: 76.92307692307692
FPS: 83.33333333333333
FPS: 83.33333333333333
FPS: 76.92307692307692
FPS: 76.92307692307692
FPS: 90.9090909090909
FPS: 76.92307692307692
FPS: 83.33333333333333
FPS: 100.0
FPS: 90.9090909090909
FPS: 100.0
FPS: 83.33333333333333
FPS: 76.92307692307692
FPS: 83.33333333333333
FPS: 100.0
```

Are there any workaround of pygame.time.Clock.tick() in java?

Comment: Use a Swing `Timer`. Never call `Thread.sleep(nn)` within a painting method.